# javascript window.location showing a blank page

Tags: javascript

I seem to be having an issue with window.location, it keeps providing a blank window, if i refresh the blank window it loads the page just fine? i am so confused here.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = '<?php echo $fburl ?>';</script>
```

if it matters this is called on a popup window, the variables and urls are correct like i said it shows the correct page once you refresh the blank window, strange. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you redirecting with JavaScript? Just send the appropriate headers with PHP.

Comment: well i have php code before the redirection, i was under the impression you could not use a header() after any other code

Comment: You can't `echo` or `print` anything, as that "ends" the HTTP headers and starts the body of the response. Including other code is fine.

Comment: correct - so that is why i went with javascript after all the code, as im echo'ing before that. is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Why do you need to echo things when you're just redirecting?

Comment: basically there are variables on that page that are generated, for instance $fburl is a unique url each time the page is loaded - which then needs to open the window.location with that url.

Comment: I'm still not sure why using a redirect header won't work: `header("Location: $fburl")`

Comment: It seems header() is the correct way to go, however it seems facebook just shows a blank page if i use that approach - if i refresh the blank window it loads fine, weird.